# php session variable not echoing

Tags: php, session, session-variables

when I run this script I am trying to echo the session variable($email)by redirecting the session via a header to location:index.php, but it just echos the session value  (the number 1) not the email address and I can't figure out why. Any Ideas? Thanks.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if ($email && $password) {
        $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could not connect");
        mysql_select_db("test") or die("could not find database");
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'&& 
            password= md5('$password')");
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if ($numrows != 0) {
            $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
            session_write_close();
            header("location:index.php");
            Die();
        }
        else
            echo ("not a user");
    }
    else
        echo("enter both fields");
}
?>
<html>
    <form action='edit1.php' method='POST'>
        <table align='right' bgcolor='blue'>
            <tr>
                <td>Email
                </td>
                <td>Password
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input name='email' type='text'>
                </td>
                <td><input name='password' type='password'><td>
                    <input type='submit' value='login'>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</html>


//index.php file

<?php
session_start(); {

    echo $_SESSION['email'] or die('fail'); {

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure $email is not 1?

Comment: no, although it is the first charicter

Comment: change echo $_SESSION['email'] or die ('fail');
to echo $_SESSION['email'];

Comment: thats it thank you so much I was loosing the will to live cant belive how simple it was can't thank you enough, your a star:D

Comment: On an unelated note, you are susceptible to sql injection (http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Please use mysql_real_escape_string, or better yet, change to PDO with prepared statements

Comment: @Utkanos: actually **everything** in php can be cast to a boolean. It won't work because `echo` always returns `void`, which is perfectly cast to `false`

Comment: @Zerkms - interesting. I'm removing my comment since it contains errors and therefore does not contribute to the page.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in the comment, the `or die` will not work. Remove it.

Comment: Thats a good point, I am planning on adding more to the scipt later. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @user1482784 you should click on the green tick next to his answer if this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the or die('fail') and it will work fine.

The function echo returns void rendering 'or die()' useless

Comment: "or die is not a valid method of the echo function" --- this phrase is terribly incorrect